# Web Ratio using a web service, how to output newline in html?

Tags: html, web-services, soap, newline

I want to use a web service provider (made by me) in my [WebRatio](http://www.webratio.com/) project, the service I developed return a string properly formatted with newline, I try to use either `\n` or the `<br>` html tag (in the output string).

In the html document, Web ratio converts `\n` in spaces and prints the `<br>` tags as text.

How can I insert html tags (like `<br>`) in the page?

Edit:
Here is the output of the service (in Java)

```
public String toString(){
    return "News \n title=" + title + "\n";} //I try using <br> instead of \n
```

And here is the html

```
<td class="value"> <!--all this HTML is printed in the same line-->
News
Titolo=bla bla

....
</td>
```

Using the `<br>` tag the main problem is to make Web Ratio avoid the conversion from the `<br>` output tag to a `&lt;br&gt;`

Comment: Your problem isn't clear bro. Put some code or show some screensshot

Comment: Ok, inserted some code. Now I think it's clear :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you resolved your problem. Anyway you can manage the text as html.

For example if you want to show the text in the Message component and set "html" as content type, please follow these steps:

1. Select the Message component in the `Layout -> Grid -> Message
   component`
2. Click on the `Layout Parameters` (blue button) of the `Component Layout` Property available in the Properties View
3. Select the option `"text/html"` for the `"Content Type"` Parameter (this is available in the `WRDefault/Normal` template).

In this way you can see the text as html.

Moreover if you want fill in a form field with the html text you have to set `"html"` as `"Content type"` Property: Select the Field in the Outline View and select `"text/html"` item for the `"Content Type"` Property available in the Properties View.

To set html as default content type for a string (or text) Attribute defined on an Entity (in the Domain Model) you can refer to the "Content Type" Property of the selected Attribute.

I hope this will help you to solve the problem.